# Python Number nodes in postorder

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, postorder

I have a binary tree with nodes like shown below.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.number = None
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

Given a tree, I want to number it from 0 in post order. An example of what I want to do

```
>>> left = Node(None, Node(3), Node(2))
>>> right = Node(None, Node(9), Node(10))
>>> node = Node(None, left, right)
>>> number(node)
>>> tree.left.number, tree.right.number, tree.number
0, 1, 2
```

However, I'm having trouble getting the right cases for the recursion part.

I am trying something like

```
def number(node, count=0):
    if not node.left and not node.right:
        node.number = count
        count += 1
    else:
        number(node.left, count)
        number(node.right, count)
```

Comment: What is the problem? I suggest adding print statements to your code to see what is happening.

Comment: What is the difference between `value` and `number`?

Comment: Does your code even compile? `Node(3)` should give an error.

Comment: Be sure to read my first comment.

Comment: @user7622302: you also introduce a `HuffmanNode` which you did not define. You perhaps better use `Node` such that the code compiles.

Comment: @user7622302 this indicates a problem with your if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- you do **not set** the `number` in the `else` case;
- you do not make implement logic **when the tree has one child**; and
- you do not **keep track** how much the counter is incremented.

You can solve these issues by **returning the `count` value** after you have assigned numbers. So something like:

```
def number(tree, count=0):
    # ...
    return new_count
```

Now the problem is how to assign numbers to the `tree` and its children. You can do this by first inspecting the left child. If it is not `None`, you call `number(..)` recursively on `tree.left` and store the returning count. Next you inspect the right child and do the same thing. Finally you assign the updated count to the `tree` itself and `return` the result. So something like:

```
def number(tree, count=0):
    if tree.left is not None:
        count = number(tree.left,count)
    if tree.right is not None:
        count = number(tree.right,count)
    tree.number = count
    return count+1
```

Running this in the console:

```
>>> leftleft = Node(3)
>>> leftright = Node(2)
>>> left = Node(None,leftleft,leftright)
>>> rightleft = Node(9)
>>> rightright = Node(10)
>>> right = Node(None,rightleft,rightright)
>>> node = Node(None, left, right)
>>> number(node)
7
>>> left.number,right.number,node.number
(2, 5, 6)
>>> leftleft.number,leftright.number,left.number,rightleft.number,rightright.number,right.number,node.number
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: @KirillBulygin: I think you miss the `count = ...` part. You thus **update** the count. Ans the count is guaranteed to be incremented with `1` since it returns `count+1`: the assignment of the last number. You can check it.

Comment: "you do not keep track how much the counter is incremented." This is key.

Comment: @user7622302: in your tree, you constructed a tree with **five nodes**...

Comment: @user7622302: see updated answer. `left` has number `2` since it has two children that are enumerated first in postfix notation.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems:

- You number only leaf nodes.
- `count` is a number, it can't be changed "by reference".

I'd suggest something like this (as a general idea):

```
def number(tree, count=0):
    node.number = count
    count += 1
    if node.left:
        count = number(node.left, count) + 1
    if node.right:
        count = number(node.right, count) + 1
    return count
```

Comment: That's **pre**order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's a **general** idea to illustrate the problems described.

Comment: "count is a number, it can't be changed "by reference"." This by far the biggest problem.